# 500 Internal Server Error Apache VHosts DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, vhosts, document-root, koken

**What I need**

I need Apache to deliver my website `website.de` with the files placed in `/var/www/html/private/koken`.

**Problem**

As for my other website I have a working configuration with VHosts I also tried it that way for this one.

On the website in question I installed the great CMS of koken.me.
After setting up the VHosts for my server I´m getting `500 Internal Server Error` with a log message of `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects` with my DocumentRoot `/var/www/html/private/koken`.
With the DocumentRoot of `/var/www/html/private` it works (delivers my test index.html).
With the working DocumentRoot I have to type `website.de/koken` and then koken works. But I don´t want to type that appendix.

**What I tried**

Changing settings in the VHosts config. But nothing else yet.
My config as of now looks like this:

```
# Personal website
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/private/koken
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.website.de
    Redirect permanent / http://website.de/
</VirtualHost>
```

**Question**

How can I instruct Apache to deliver the index.php in the koken folder when I type in my website name `website.de`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My VHosts config was fine.

The problem was the koken `.htaccess` file.

As per my Apache config the `DocumentRoot` points to the files inside the koken folder on the server.

But the `.htaccess` of koken states a `RewriteBase` of `/koken` so the requests are pointing to a non-existing place (that is `koken/koken/`).

Therefore I had to write `RewriteBase /` and do a find/replace on `/koken/` to `/`.

Now koken is aligned to my Apache pointer and the site runs as fresh as daisy.

Hope I can help someone `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, the following should fit your needs:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.de
    ServerAlias www.website.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/private/koken
</VirtualHost>
```

The second virtual host is not needed as far as I can see it.

Comment: Thanks, FrW, for your commitment. However it was something different. See my answer.